# How to change the name of the dictionary while iterating over it?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I change the name of the dictionary while, iterating it over a while-loop(or any other)... so that it saves the input information in a dictionary with different name every single time?

This would save the information(as a dictionary) in different names(like biodata1, biodata2, etc...) so that processing those informations become easy!!

```
    ans = input("Can we start?[(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
    ans.lower()
    while ans == "y":

        # Name
        name = input("Name: ")
        # -----------------------
        # Age
        age = int(input("Age: "))
        if age >= 18:
            soc_stat = "Adult"
        else:
            soc_stat = "Minor"
        # -----------------------
        # DOB
        dob = input('''
        Enter your D.O.B. in D, M, Y format
        [must include comma after each item, 
        but don't finish with comma]: ''')
        # ------------------------------
        # E-Mail
        email = input("Your E-Mail id: ")
        # ------------------------
        # Gender
        gender = input("(M)ale or (F)emale: ")
        gender.lower()
        if gender == "m":
            gender = "Male"
        elif gender == "f":
            gender = "Female"
        # -----------------------
        # Criminal Records
        crim = input("Do you have any criminal records(your input will be cross-checked)[(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
        crim.lower()
        if crim == "y":
            has_criminal_records = True
        elif crim == "n":
            has_criminal_records = False

        biodata = {
            "Name": name,
            "Age": age,
            "DOB": (dob[0], dob[1], dob[2]),
            "Social status": soc_stat,
            "EMail": email,
            "Gender": gender,
            "Criminal records": has_criminal_records,
        }
        break
```

Comment: you have to rewrite values like `biodata['Name'] = name`

Comment: Do not change variable names, use another dict arround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would advice would be instead of while loop define function that will perform codes inside your loop and after append your dictionary to a list.

Your code should be like this:

```
biodata_list= []

def biodata_input():
    ans = input("Can we start?[(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
    ans.lower()

    if ans == "y":
        # Name
        name = input("Name: ")
        # -----------------------
        # Age
        age = int(input("Age: "))
        if age >= 18:
            soc_stat = "Adult"
        else:
            soc_stat = "Minor"
        # -----------------------
        # DOB
        dob = input('''
                Enter your D.O.B. in D, M, Y format
                [must include comma after each item, 
                but don't finish with comma]: ''')
        # ------------------------------
        # E-Mail
        email = input("Your E-Mail id: ")
        # ------------------------
        # Gender
        gender = input("(M)ale or (F)emale: ")
        gender.lower()
        if gender == "m":
            gender = "Male"
        elif gender == "f":
            gender = "Female"
        # -----------------------
        # Criminal Records
        crim = input("Do you have any criminal records(your input will be cross-checked)[(Y)es or (N)o]: ")
        crim.lower()
        if crim == "y":
            has_criminal_records = True
        elif crim == "n":
            has_criminal_records = False

        biodata_dict = {
            "Name": name,
            "Age": age,
            "DOB": (dob[0], dob[1], dob[2]),
            "Social status": soc_stat,
            "EMail": email,
            "Gender": gender,
            "Criminal records": has_criminal_records,
        }
        biodata_list.append(biodata_dict)

biodata_input()
print(biodata_list)
```

With this way you have to call biodata_input() function each time you want user to input data. You can get this into while loop if you are going to ask endlessly for input.

One think I noticed, your age input is written like below;

```
age = int(input("Age: "))
```

So if user types a character by mistake this will cause Value Error and script will exit. Instead after age input, you can check for type, and if its not an integer you can ask for input again.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I got it!

Comment: There's plenty of additional validation to do beyond age (which shouldn't be negative, >200, and could actually be calculated from the DOB in the first place). DOB format isn't checked, may not be a real day, month, or year, and may be a time in the future, or the distant distant past. email may be an empty string, or not an email. Gender (IRL and in the given input) may not be male or female. Has criminal records may be left neither True or False if the user doesn't answer, or answers with y or n. Good luck polishing this!

Comment: Thanks for the info... As a beginner I really appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary doesn't have a name, per se. There is a refence to a dictionary in a variable named `biodata`. On each iteration, the variable contains a reference to a different dictionary with different data from the user.

You may want to attach that dictionary object to some other data structure. Perhaps a list:

```
all_biodata = [];
...
while ...:
    ...
    all_biodata.append(biodata)
```

Once that loop has ended, you'll have a list of all biodata entries.

Note that your loop appears to continue infinitely. You may need to change `ans` to cause it to exit at some point, perhaps by prompting the user for an indication of whether to continue looping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Luke!... I got that one!